# CRUD in domain driven design

Tags: domain-driven-design

To perform CRUD operation in domain driven design, do i need to create a **domain service per root aggregate** which will have store method, this method will call **repository interface which have concrete implementation in infrastructure layer**. Is this the correct approach. **Please correct me if i am wrong**.

Comment: In my opinion, you don't need that 'domain service' since it'll only delegate the responsability to the repository and nothing else. Why not calling the repository directly?

Answer (score 1):

I mostly agree:

The repository interfaces are part of the model layer and are implemented in the infrastructure layer. But keep in mind, that repositories are like collection and store complete objects. They are not modeled like a persistency layer and thus cannot store parts of aggregate roots. To construct complex aggregate roots a factory can be used.

Also remember that an effective design has to depend on the (persistence) technologies used.

Answer (score 1):

CRUD doesn't work well with domain driven design. In domain driven design you work with verbs and nouns of the domain. Instead of "create a new order" you have a user aggregate root which "places an order". If your system is full of CRUD-operations, you are not utilizing domain driven design as it should be utilized, and instead you are just adding complexity to an otherwise simple problem.

An administration screen is a good candidate for CRUD. You have some list of some items, where addition or modification do not have business (domain) rules that need to be enforced. It's just plain "insert new row, modify that row, delete that row".

An order processing system is more complex, and will start to benefit from domain driven design. "Place an order". "Pay order". "When an order is placed and payment is done, start shipping process". These have complex rules that need to be modeled in the domain, and hence, domain driven design is a good candidate.